# ExtJs dynamically building a formpanel from a datastore record

Tags: forms, extjs, dynamic

I am trying to dynamically populate a ExtJs FormPanel from a datastore record.
When the user clicks on a row in the GridPanel, the buildForm method is called and the clicked record is sent passed in as the first arg.

The below code (when debugging) appears to be working, but the **doLayout** method has no effect.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
mymodule = Ext.extend(Ext.FormPanel, {
    forceLayout: true,
    initComponent: function () {
        Ext.applyIf(this, {
            id: Ext.id(),
            labelWidth: 75,
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            items: [{
                layout: 'form',
                items: [{
                    fieldLabel: 'test',
                    xtype: 'textfield'
                }, {
                    fieldLabel: 'test',
                    xtype: 'textfield'
                }]
            }]
        });
        mymodule.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    },
    buildForm: function (record, c) {
        var form = this.getForm();

        var formItems = new Ext.util.MixedCollection();

        Ext.each(record.fields.items, function (item) {
            formItems.add(new Ext.form.TextField({
                labelStyle: 'width:100px',
                fieldLabel: item.name,
                name: item.dataIndex,
                id: 'field-' + item.name
            }));
        }, this);

        form.items = formItems;

        this.doLayout(false, true);

        form.loadRecord(record);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to add components to the form would be to use the `add()` method. If your form is already rendered, use the `add()` method and then call `doLayout()`.

So you might want to try this:

```
form.add(formItems);
form.doLayout(false,true);
form.loadRecord(record);
```

Comment: thanks, in that case what is the correct way to remove items? As I need to clear the form first

Comment: you can use `remove()` or `removeAll()` methods to remove components from the form